# How to get twitter widget to reappear with Turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, widget, turbolinks

If you use Turbolinks in Rails 4 and you view a landing page that has a Twitter widget for a user's profile, and then you view another page, and then back to the landing page... the Twitter widget will no longer be a JS widget. It's just a placeholder link. How do you re-init the Twitter widget in this case?

Comment: How are you including the Twitter JS widget? Can you include some code?

Answer (score 0):

May want to look at [JQuery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just upgraded to Rails 4 and I got hit with a similar problem. The turbolinks documentation has an [Opting Out of turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks) section, which explains how to mark a link or its parent container with `data-no-turbolink`. I'm seeing this problem linking back to my homepage in a bootstrap navbar **and** I'm using HAML, so I ended up doing this:

```
%header{class: 'navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'}
  %div{class: 'navbar-inner', 'data-no-turbolink' => true}
    .container
      = link_to 'example.com', root_path, id: 'go_home'

...
```

which renders as

```
<header class='navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'>
  <div class='navbar-inner' data-no-turbolink>
    <div class='container'>
      <a href="/" id="go_home">example.com</a>
```

and because it's for the whole navbar-inner div, a later explicit link to the text **home** is also covered.